# Postgresql For loop with update inside function

Tags: database, postgresql, for-loop

I'm trying to use a postgresql function to initiate a query against a couple of tables and then do an insert into another table if the criteria are met. I'm getting errors around the declaration or the return statement every time. Any help is appreciated.

Basically this should:

1. Loop against the health_alerts_triggered table and use field data in each row to then query the "healthEvents" table
2. If the count in the subquery for "healthEvents" returns greater than zero rows and insert should be done into the health_alerts_triggered table.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_alertcheck() 
   RETURNS SETOF record;
   DECLARE r record;
   FOR r IN SELECT * 
       FROM health_alerts_config
   LOOP
   INSERT INTO health_alerts_triggered (health_affiliate_id, alert_format,alert_minutes, health_client_internal_id, alert_triggered_date, alert_processed_date, alert_id, affiliate_name, client_name)
   VALUES (r.health_affiliate_id, r.alert_format, r.alert_minutes, r.health_client_internal_id, now() as alert_triggered_date, '' as alert_processed_date, id, ha.health_affiliate_description, hc.health_client_description)
   WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) from "heatlhEvents" he 
      WHERE he.format = r.format,
      AND he.healthaffiliatclientid = r.health_affiliate_description,
      AND he.timestamp > Now() - r.minutes
       )
       > 0
   INNER JOIN health_affiliates ha
   ON r.health_affiliate_id = ha.id
   INNER JOIN health_clients hc
   ON r.health_client_internal_id = hc.id
   END LOOP;
   RETURN result;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
   ```

Schema for health_alerts_config:

```
CREATE TABLE public.health_alerts_config
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"healthAlerts_id_seq"'::regclass),
    health_affiliate_id bigint NOT NULL,
    alert_format character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    alert_minutes integer NOT NULL,
    health_client_internal_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT health_alerts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Sample row: 1,1,ADT,60,1

Schema for health_affiliates

```
CREATE TABLE public.health_affiliates
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    health_affiliate_description character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT health_affiliates_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Sample row: 1, 'TestCo'

Schema for health_clients

```
CREATE TABLE public.health_clients
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"healthClients_id_seq"'::regclass),
    health_affiliate integer NOT NULL,
    health_client_id character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    health_client_description character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Sample row: 1, 1, 200, 'TestCoClient'

Schema for "healthEvents"

```
CREATE TABLE public."healthEvents"
(
    "ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"healthEvents_ID_seq"'::regclass),
    "fileName" character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "instanceName" character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "channelName" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    affiliate character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "fileSizeKB" bigint,
    "beginProcessing" timestamp without time zone,
    "endProcessing" timestamp without time zone,
    resubmission boolean NOT NULL,
    destination integer NOT NULL,
    "insertTime" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "messageID" bigint NOT NULL,
    direction integer NOT NULL,
    "affiliateClient" character varying(40) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "messageType" character varying(15) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "messageStatus" integer,
    "messageCode" character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "insertDate" date DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date,
    "affiliateClientID" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
```

)

Comment: Please provide the schema of health_alerts_config and healthaffiliatclientid with some data

Comment: Added the detail you asked for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you even need a loop here. I'd do something like (untested):

```
INSERT INTO health_alerts_triggered (
  health_affiliate_id, alert_format, alert_minutes, health_client_internal_id,
  alert_triggered_date, alert_processed_date, alert_id,
  affiliate_name, client_name
)
SELECT
  r.health_affiliate_id, r.alert_format, r.alert_minutes, r.health_client_internal_id,
  now() as alert_triggered_date, '' as alert_processed_date, id,
  ha.health_affiliate_description, hc.health_client_description
FROM
  health_alerts_config r
  INNER JOIN health_affiliates ha
    ON r.health_affiliate_id = ha.id
  INNER JOIN health_clients hc
    ON r.health_client_internal_id = hc.id
WHERE
  exists(
    SELECT 1
    FROM "heatlhEvents" he 
    WHERE he.format = r.format,
    AND he.healthaffiliatclientid = r.health_affiliate_description,
    AND he.timestamp > now() - r.minutes
  )
;
```

Comment: Looks promising, I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the reply!